# На каких объектах происходит lock?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Написал код, ожидал что lock в методах addToList будет происходить на одном и том же объекте а точнее worker, но судя по тестам lock происходит на разных объектах. Вопрос на каких? Не на тредах же

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
       Worker worker = new Worker();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
            worker.doWork();
        });

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
            worker.doWork();
        });

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

    }

}

class Worker {

    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

    public synchronized void addToList1(){
            list1.add(random.nextInt(100));
    }

    public synchronized void addToList2(){
            list2.add(random.nextInt(100));
    }

    public void doWork()  {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                addToList1();
                addToList2();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `судя по тестам lock происходит на разных объектах` как вы это определили?

Comment: по времени выполнении программы

Comment: Это как? У вас есть эталонное значения времени, которое должна выполняться данная программа на вашем конкретном компе и на конкретной jre при синхронизированных методах на одном объекте и на нескольких да ещё и на таком маленьком тесте? В любом случая синхронизация происходит на объекте в котором вызывают нестатические `synchronized` методы (`worker` в данном случае).  К тому же вы забыли `thread1.join();` `thread2.join();`, ваша программа завершается, не успев даже запустить потоки...

Comment: @IR42 она не завершается и здесь не нужны join'ы. Это же не потоки-демоны

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин lock происходит на одном и том же объекте. Как уже сказали выше, когда syncronized метод не статический, ему в качестве объекта lock'a передается this

Comment: да, ошибся, join не нужен

Comment: ну я явно синхронизировал на разных объектах и время выполнение было таким же как и в примере выше, при этом когда я синхронизирую на одном объекте время выполнения увеличивается в 2 раза, как это объяснить?